# What happens when we delete the google account of a project owner?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

What happens when we delete or deactivate the google account of the project owner, who’s also the creator of file attached to the Cloud Project? Do other owners (set up in Google Cloud Platform) keep their authorizations?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question body should include all the relevant details. Is this question about a Google Apps Script project? Is the project owned by a gmail.com account or by a Google Workspace account? Is the project in the user Drive or on a Shared Drive? Also please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Edit your question with details. My suggestion: before deleting a Google account (Gmail, Workspace, etc) verify that another identity has the Owner role (and test that) and then remove the other identity. After you verify that no problems arise, then delete the other identity.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this is really a customer service question. Not something for Stack Overflow (not related to programming, and this site isn't a direct product-support site for any company)

Answer (score 0):

If the account belong to an organisation, the project continue to live in the organisation and the org admin is able to access it, go to IAM page and to grant a new owner (or not, an owner is not required on a project!)

If you expect notification on the project, the [essential contact feature](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-notification-contacts) is done for that

If the account is a personal account, you can't recover the project, it is lost.